# intel hd graphics 620 driver for windows 8 64 bits

Tags: windows-8, device-driver

People, I really don´t know if this question is out of place here but I RAN OUT OF OPTIONS.

I recently bought a laptop: [Acer aspire e15 e5-575-33bm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K1IO3QW).

I can do everything I thought I would be able to do with it when I bought it, except for one tiny detail which slipped me: it has got a 7th gen core i3 processor WHICH HAS LITTLE TO NO SUPPORT IN WINDOWS 8.

Believe me, I have spent lots of time looking for a compatible driver and everywhere I go (acer.com, drp.su, gigahax.com, guru3d.com, and many others although these have been the closest) I find, to my disbelieve, Intel HD Graphics 620 drivers compliant with Win7, Win8.1 and Win10 (although officially it´s supposed to have only win10 support) and I´m like HELLO!, I know win8 is not exactly the first choice for millions of people who felt "lost" when their precious start button was taken away from them but this is too much, it even looks like it was left out on purpose.

Anyway sorry, wrapping up: does anyone have a clue of where I could look to find drivers for a 7th gen core I3 processor with Intel HD Graphics 620 FOR WIN8 PLEASE. I don't even play big fancy games (as u can tell by the specs of the latpop), all I want is to be able to take as much advantage of the hardware I bought as possible.

And just to prove to you how desperate I am, if you find any other driver that could take me half way there (dunno if that even exists) and that could be compatible, I'll take it as well

thank you

EDIT: switching to any other windows distribution is NOT an option, especially not win10

Comment: I will not be able to convince you...but what do you see in Windows 8 better than in Windows 10?

Comment: @YisroelTech; u r right, u wont

Comment: If you can't switch to another Windows version, why don't you install GNU/Linux instead?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to run Windows 8 on a system designed for Windows 10, but be that as it may, [According to Intel your CPU has  Intel HD Graphics 630 graphics](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/processors/corei3/sb/IntelCorei3ComparisonChart.pdf). Assuming the 620 listed in the Amazon ad is a typo and that Intel knows better what their CPU's have than Amazon does, Intel offers several versions of a Intel HD 630 graphics driver installer that's compatible with Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 (64-bit versions) available for download [here.](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/98909/Intel-HD-Graphics-630)

Full disclosure: As I don't have your hardware and OS, I am unable to test, but hopefully this will get you where you wish to be.

Sources:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01K1IO3QW/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K1IO3QW)

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/processors/corei3/sb/IntelCorei3ComparisonChart.pdf

Comment: after weeks of trying I HAD to install win10(I can still hear MS laughing in my face). In short, any intel hd graphics I tried just wouldnt work on win8(which i still like a lot better), if u can't beat them... 
Regarding the graphics ¿version?, r u sure? see, i haven't looked that hard but everywhere i look including [here](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.GG5AA.005) and the sticker by the keyboard say 620, not 630. thanx for the links BUT i cant dwnld anythng from intel.com from my country,2 bad, i really wanted that chart, i would still upvote but wont let me, sorry and thanx

Comment: I'm sorry you were unable to implement my answer. I expect it will be useful for others in your situation who can access intel.com

Comment: it´s ok, now i was wondering if u could do me the huge favor of posting that chart somewhere i could download it from, if possible of course, it´d be a great reference, thanx any way

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría You have my apologies but that document is copyrighted and I cannot legally comply with your request.